# Destroy a specific $_SESSION

Tags: php, session

I'm busy with my shopping cart but i can't get past this problem. Whenever a user clicks on home, the session that holds products is not destroyed. It should be destroyed because there is an option that a user wants to order something by another business. How can i achieve this?

This creates a $*SESSION['cart*'].

```
if(isset($_GET['add'])) {
    $cart = $_SESSION['cart_' . $_GET['add']]+='1';
    $_SESSION['cart'] = '1';
}
```

I've tried destroying this:

```
for ($i=0; $i <2 ; $i++) { 
    $_SESSION['cart_' . $i] = '0';
    session_unset($_SESSION['cart_' . $i]);
}
```

What am i doing wrong? I just want to destroy the session is a user clicks on home or wants to browse other businesses.

Comment: It's marked a dup while I was posting, but here's my comment That's because you are using the wrong item.  It's `unset($_SESSION['cart'.$i])`  `session_unset` kills all the variables.  also you should set `$_SESSION['cart_'].$i] = '';` not zero because until the browser leaves, that cart variable is still live.